# Cannot be resolved into a valid type or function

Tags: c#, sql, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to build an OData endpoint for a Table valued function in sql database. My routing and controller is correct, however I get the error

```
'DataAccessFunctionEntities.GetConfiguration' ---> DataAccess.. is where I built a model
 cannot be resolved into a valid type or function.
```

although the Get Configuration function is in my controller.

I have tried debugging and get the same error. I can't find on how to resolve this error.

Thanks

Calling DB function (inside Controller) gives error: The DB function:

```
[DbFunction("DataAccessFunctionEntities", "GetConfiguration")]
public virtual IQueryable<GetConfiguration_Result> GetConfiguration(string partialPIDs)
{
    var partialPIDsParameter = partialPIDs != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("PartialPIDs", partialPIDs) :
        new ObjectParameter("PartialPIDs", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<GetConfiguration_Result>("[DataAccessFunctionEntities].[GetConfiguration](@PartialPIDs)", partialPIDsParameter);
}
```

The routing is directing the request to correct function. Here is the controller function :

```
        [HttpGet,EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult GetConfiguration(ODataQueryOptions<GetConfiguration_Result> options)
        {
            string errorType = string.Empty;
            string exServerName = string.Empty;
            int exErrorNumber = 0;
            string exErrorMessage = string.Empty;
            string exStackTrace = string.Empty;
            var inputparameter = "NONE";

            if (options == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("options");

            var uri = options.Request.RequestUri.ToString();
            //Decode url for Page-2 and beyond            
            if (uri.Contains("%"))
            {
                uri = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri);
            }
            var firstOpenParenthesisIndex = uri.Substring(uri.IndexOf("(", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1);
            var equalsOperatorIndex = firstOpenParenthesisIndex.Substring(firstOpenParenthesisIndex.IndexOf("=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1);
            var partialPIds = equalsOperatorIndex.Substring(0, equalsOperatorIndex.IndexOf(")", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            inputparameter = partialPIds;
            var validationResponse = ProcessInput.ValidatePartialPID(partialPIds);
            // Intial Request Logging
            var requestLog = new RequestLog
            {
                Source = "Configuration-GET",
                RequestUrl = options.Request.RequestUri.ToString(),
                UserName = User.Identity.Name,
                StartTime = DateTime.Now,
                EndTime = null,
                RequestStatus = RequestStatus.STARTED.ToString(),
                RequestLength = validationResponse.ParameterCount,
                ResponseLength = 0,
                QueryOptions = ProcessInput.ExtractQueryOptions(options.Request.RequestUri),
                ParentId = null
            };
            var errorlog = new ErrorLog
            {
                RequestLogId = 0,
                ErrorCode = 0,
                ErrorDescription = ""

            };

            if (isLoggingEnabled)
            {
                requestLog.ParentId = _dbLogHelper.LogRequest(requestLog);
            }

            try
            {
                if (validationResponse.IsValidInput == false)
                {
                    requestLog.RequestStatus = RequestStatus.FAIL.ToString();
                    _shortMessage = string.Format(_validationErrorShortMessage, requestLog.Source, validationResponse.InvalidInputMessage, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    _type = EventLogEntryType.Error;
                    _returnCode = ReturnCodes.ValidationErrorCode;
                    _returnCodeCategory = ReturnCodes.ValidationErrorCode;

                    errorType = "ValidationError";

                    throw new PAIntelODataException(
                        _shortMessage,
                        ODataLogCategory.ValidationException,
                        ReturnCodes.ValidationErrorCode,
                        requestLog.Source);
                }

                partialPIds = validationResponse.XmlPartialPIDs.ToString();

                IQueryable<GetConfiguration_Result> result;
                try
                {
                    result = _DataAccessFunction.GetConfiguration(partialPIds);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    requestLog.RequestStatus = RequestStatus.FAIL.ToString();
                    _type = EventLogEntryType.Error;
                    _returnCode = ReturnCodes.DatabaseErrorCode;
                    _returnCodeCategory = ReturnCodes.DatabaseErrorCode;

                    var innerException = ex;
                    if (ex.InnerException != null)
                    {
                        while (!(innerException is SqlException))
                        {
                            innerException = innerException.InnerException;
                        }
                        var sqlEx = innerException as SqlException;

                        _shortMessage = string.Format(_sqlErrorShortMessage, requestLog.Source, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                        errorType = "SQLError";
                        exServerName = sqlEx.Server;
                        exErrorNumber = sqlEx.Number;
                        exErrorMessage = sqlEx.Message;
                        exStackTrace = sqlEx.StackTrace;

                        throw new PAIntelODataException(
                            _shortMessage,
                            sqlEx,
                            ODataLogCategory.DbException,
                            ReturnCodes.DatabaseErrorCode,
                            sqlEx.Source);
                    }
                    _shortMessage = string.Format(_sqlErrorShortMessage, requestLog.Source, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    errorType = "SQLGenearalError";
                    exErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                    exStackTrace = ex.StackTrace;

                    throw new PAIntelODataException(
                        _shortMessage,
                        ex,
                        ODataLogCategory.DbException,
                        ReturnCodes.DatabaseErrorCode,
                        requestLog.Source);
                }
                if (result != null)
                {
                    requestLog.RequestStatus = RequestStatus.SUCCESS.ToString();
                    requestLog.ResponseLength = result.ToString().Length;
                    _type = EventLogEntryType.Information;
                    _returnCode = ReturnCodes.Success;
                    _returnCodeCategory = ReturnCodes.Success;
                    errorType = "None";
                    _message = string.Format(_successfulCall, requestLog.Source, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    return Ok(result, result.GetType());
                }
                return null;
            }

            catch (PAIntelODataException)
            {
                throw;
            }

            finally
            {
                requestLog.EndTime = DateTime.Now;

                //Perform Logging
                //Database Logging:
                if (isLoggingEnabled)
                {
                    var ChildId = _dbLogHelper.LogRequest(requestLog);

                    if (_type == EventLogEntryType.Error)
                    {
                        errorlog.RequestLogId = ChildId;
                        errorlog.ErrorCode = _returnCode;
                        errorlog.ErrorDescription = _shortMessage;
                        _dbLogHelper.LogErrorDetails(errorlog);
                    }
                }

                //EventViewer Logging:
                if (_type == EventLogEntryType.Error)
                {
                    switch (errorType)
                    {
                        case "ValidationError":
                            _message = string.Format(_validationErrorLongMessage, requestLog.Source, requestLog.Source, requestLog.RequestUrl, inputparameter, requestLog.QueryOptions, errorlog.RequestLogId, requestLog.UserName, requestLog.StartTime, requestLog.EndTime, validationResponse.InvalidInputMessage, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); ;
                            break;
                        case "SQLError":
                            _message = string.Format(_sqlErrorLongMessage, requestLog.Source, exServerName, exErrorNumber, requestLog.Source, requestLog.RequestUrl, inputparameter, requestLog.QueryOptions, errorlog.RequestLogId, requestLog.UserName, requestLog.StartTime, requestLog.EndTime, exErrorMessage, exStackTrace, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            break;
                        case "SQLGenearalError":
                            _message = string.Format(_sqlErrorLongAbbreviatedMessage, requestLog.Source, requestLog.Source, requestLog.RequestUrl, inputparameter, requestLog.QueryOptions, errorlog.RequestLogId, requestLog.UserName, requestLog.StartTime, requestLog.EndTime, exErrorMessage, exStackTrace, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            break;
                    }

                    LogHelper.WriteToEventLog(_message, requestLog.Source, _type, _returnCode, _returnCodeCategory);
                }

            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && _AccessModel != null)
            {
                _AccessModel.Dispose();
            }

            if (disposing && _DataAccessFunction != null)
            {
                _DataAccessFunction.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You may Show some source-code to help us identify the Problem.

Comment: And where (and how) is that method declared? Please do not post whole source-code, pnly the relevant parts.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I posted the method only

Comment: Obviously your method-signature expects a `ODataQueryOptions<GetConfiguration_Result>` and not a  `string`  (what `partialIDs` is)

Comment: @HimBromBeere plz see one more edit. thanks a lot for your help. The error comes in the call of a function inside .. you could see a model being built in the first lines .

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently. My DBContext was generated by Importing database model using EF6 (database first).

I think the issue was caused by the fact that after the code was generated I have renamed the DBContext class to my need. The project rebuild successfully but at run-time I got the exact same error: `'MyDataContext.my_fn_name' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function. Near member access expression, line 1, column 23.`

I re-generated the Database model again and adjust the class name in my other files and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to register the complex type for the result object?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    // Add functions on to entity model.
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention<xxxxxYourEntitiesxxxxx>());

    // tvf types
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<GetConfiguration_Result>();

}
```

And add the ComplexType attribute to your result class

```
[ComplexType]
public class GetConfiguration_Result
{
    //..
}
```

Also, your function declaration will need to specify the namespace

```
[Function(FunctionType.TableValuedFunction, "GetConfiguration", namespaceName : "xxxxxYourEntitiesxxxxx",  Schema = "dbo")]
public virtual IQueryable<GetConfiguration_Result> GetConfiguration(string partialPIDs)
```

Comment: I used the first part of your answer to resolve my problem. I did not need to use the attribute on the class. I used the fluent assertion setup in the override.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was migrating a function from one DBContext object to another, and I got this error `'MyDataContext.my_fn_name' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function` because I was missing the line

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention<MyDataContext>("schemaName"));
```

in `OnModelCreating`.